# Determine the amp hour rating of a home made battery pack

Tags: capacity, ampere-hour

I'm thinking of making my own electric bicycle, and I need help determining what the amp hour rating of my battery pack would be. I'm going for 36v and 8 or 9 amp hours. 
So, with 10 batteries in series, I can get a single, low capacity pack with 36v. If I were to make three of these, and put those in parallel, I'd have three times the capacity. But, with each battery providing 2500mah, that's 75 amp hours, and I know that's not correct. What am I forgetting? [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8NHy.jpg) according to my knowledge and to the picture, series doubles the voltage and the capacity stays the same

Comment: Two obligatory safety warnings: 1) You will need to ensure voltage balance between series connected batteries somehow. 2) Cell-integrated protection circuits cannot protect a battery pack due to too high reverse voltage, so you need a whole-pack protection circuit.

Answer (score 3):

If you series connect the batteries the amp-hour rating stays the same. The voltage has increased though, so the *power* available has increased. That's why using watt-hours is more useful than amp-hours when comparing battery packs of different voltages.

So ...

- If you're using 10 x 3.6 V batteries in a string you have a 36 V, 2.5 Ah battery.
- That's a 36 V x 2.5 Ah = 90 Wh (watt-hour) battery.
- Put three of those packs in parallel and you get a 36 V, 7.5 Ah battery.
- That's a 36 V x 7.5 A = 270 Wh battery.

Now here's where watt-hours are so much more useful. Let's say you're going to need 135 W average power for your motor. Your battery duration will be 270 Wh / 135 W = 2 hours duration.

My electric bike uses about 150 W in normal cycling mode at almost 30 kph. I reckon my legs are putting in another 150 W.

Little technical point: In the SI system of units it's capital letters for abbreviated units named after someone but lower-case when spelled out: V for volt, A for amp, W for watt, etc. Yes, there will be exceptions ...

Answer (score 2):

Showing my work:

2.5 amp hours (one cell) at 36 volts (10 cells in series) is 90 watt-hours.

Times 3 of these strings in parallel is still 36 volts (you knew that) and 7.5 amp hours or 270 watt hours.

So I think you forgot a decimal point.  :-)

---

Side note about connecting batteries in parallel: If you can avoid it, don't!  Use higher capacity batteries instead.  The reason appears when one cell gets weak or fails short-circuit while the others are still good:

If you have one series string and that happens, the pack voltage drops and you have to replace that one cell.  Inconvenient, but still the best of all scenarios.

If you have multiple strings in parallel, current can flow backwards through the string that contains the bad cell, potentially damaging the entire string.

If you tie across all the strings at each level, making one series string where each "cell" is actually a parallel combination of cells, then you're pretty much guaranteed to lose an entire "rung" at once because the bad cell will drag the rest down with it.

And there's the issue of how much current actually flows in each scenario.  For example, when you first connect the batteries in parallel, whether single cells or strings of cells, they will be charged to slightly different voltages (nothing is ever equal, including end-of-charge from the same charger at different times), which will be imposed across the wires that connect the strings.  How much current is that?

Comment: I think the 75 Ah came from multiplying the cell amp-hour rating by the number of cells. You correctly calculate the total as 7.5 Ah.

Comment: However, if you isolate each string with a diode, you can avoid the problems you discuss.

Comment: https://www.electricbike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/BatteryDIY11.png Why are the batteries welded like they are?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: But then you have diode losses.  That can be (mostly) overcome with a FET-based ideal diode, but now we're getting complicated.

Comment: @Hellreaver: How cheap is that pack compared to the rest of the market?  Ignoring the initial connection, that will work until one cell dies, at which point the entire rung dies.

Comment: @AaronD - Yeah, but a Schottky diode dropping 0.5 volts on a 36 volt string is less than a 2% loss.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: I was thinking more about heat.

Comment: @AaronD I figured I'd use Samsung 18650 cells.

Comment: @Hellreaver  "Why are the batteries welded like they are?" That pack uses 15 cells in parallel per voltage level. What you are seeing is the connection of two levels, so a total of 30 cells are connected. The other side is connected in much the same way, but there will be 15 cells connected at one end and 15 at the other.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/p8NHy.jpg isn't this how parallel and series work?

Comment: Related http://www.catastrophenetwork.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Circuits.jpg

Comment: @Hellreaver: In a very simplistic way, yes.  *IF* all cells are *exactly* identical, which they never are, then it works like that.  The trouble is that slight differences get amplified into the problems that I described in my original answer.  This is also why purely series strings still need to be balanced periodically; differences between cells over several cycles will cause one to overcharge while another isn't fully charged yet, so the ones with slightly less capacity need to have some of their charge bled off or transferred to the others before they overcharge.

Comment: @AaronD and not equalizing them could result in failures, fires, etc. Isn't that how a lithium ion charger works? And is there any way for me to get around that problem that you see me actually accomplishing?

Comment: @AaronD also, if I need 36v and 10 cells to achieve that, could I use like 12 cells and only charge them each to 3v, to negate the potential difference in peak charge?

Comment: @Hellreaver: If the charger has a balancing port and that mode is active, yes, but even that has no idea how many you have in parallel, nor does it really need to.  If you do it that way, you pretty much have to use the ladder idea, where you have a single series string that ties across multiple cells per rung, and you only tell the charger the total capacity.  But you still have the problem of one failed cell killing its entire rung.  If it fails catastrophically, not only do you have its energy to deal with, but all the energy in its entire rung will be released as well.

Comment: @Hellreaver: You'd lose a lot of capacity by partial charging, and you wouldn't solve anything.  The problem is the charger's cutoff voltage, which is different per charger, per temperature, per noise, per everything.  Nothing is ever equal, regardless of whether you turn it down or use the full scale.

Comment: @AaronD that's another issue. If I were to make this pack, the heat output would be pretty decent. Maybe a heatsink would help?

Comment: @Hellreaver: Heatsink on what?  The diodes?  If you absolutely can't get higher-capacity cells, then that's probably the next best thing.  Assume that any one string can take all the load for a while and size the diodes and heatsink(s) for that.  Eventually, it'll get down to another string's voltage and the two will share the load, then they'll reach the third's, and so on.  Charge and balance each string independently.

Comment: @AaronD I see 6v lithium ion batteries at 4.5ah.

Comment: @Hellreaver That would be 2 cells in series, so keep that in mind.  Otherwise, it's an improvement.  It's not the 7.5Ah that you were originally looking for, but if you can get a higher voltage motor you can make a single series string that's that much longer and end up with the correct Wh, which is really what matters.

Comment: @Hellreaver It would take 60V at 4.5Ah to get the same Wh as you had originally, which is over the 50V that is typically considered "safe" for muggles.  (highly arbitrary, but you have to draw the line somewhere)  Or if you're okay with 48V, you would have 216Wh in a single string instead of 270 across three strings.

Answer (score 1):

The same current goes through batteries in series, therefore the capacity in Ah is not the sum of the individual batteries, it's the same. The overall energy in Wh is increased because the voltage of the battery pack increases. If you want more capacity in Ah, you need to put several 36V stacks in parallel; 3 of them in parallel will give you  7.5Ah.

That's purely to answer your question, though you should watch out for cell failure modes and charge balancing.

Comment: The linked picture is correct... In what way do you think it is conflicting with what I wrote?

Comment: I was trying to make the distinction that I would be  using many cells in series to increase the voltage, and three of those packs to increase the amp hour rating.

Comment: Yes, but in that case you will only multiply the amp hour rating by 3, not 30 as your "75" figure suggests.